# is there a way to fallback nginx proxy_pass if header set

Tags: nginx, amazon-s3

nginx server serves http://server1.com, http://server2.com and http://server3.com.

nginx upstreams request process to some ruby code.

server1.com, server2.com and server3.com are actually some static files stored on amazon s3.

I want to do next: find bucket name for 'server1' host, put in db some logs and notify nginx to stream from amazon.
Maybe via setting in ruby code header with url to amazon s3 bucket and using this url later by nginx.

The flow: browser -> nginx -> ruby -> nginx -> amazon_s3 -> browser

I found how i can do this on error:

```
http {
  server {
     listen 12345; #Port that my custom app was assigned
     server_name mydomain.com;

     location / {
       proxy_intercept_errors on;
       error_page 400 403 502 503 504 = @fallback;
       proxy_pass http://the_old_site_domain.com;      
     }

     location @fallback {
       proxy_pass http://myfallback.domain.com;
     }
  }
}
```

But is there a way to do something similar based on header appereance?

Thanks!

UPD
This is how i can test my header:

```
if ($http_x_custom_header) {
  ....
}
```

If set nginx should do some internal redirect, right?

But how it can be invoked *after* ruby code?

Comment: http://wiki.nginx.org/X-accel#X-Accel-Redirect

Comment: Thanks! Can you please make it an answer? so i can accept it? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is special headers called `X-Accel-...`.
You need [`X-Accel-Redirect`](http://wiki.nginx.org/X-accel#X-Accel-Redirect).